# What do you call the subset of all the Gaussian integers having the smallest magnitude given an argument?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

How is called the subset of Gaussian integers such that from all Gaussian integers having the same argument only one with the smallest absolute value is included?

Is there a special name for them? Were they studied before?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Did you perhaps intend to write "only one with the smallest **magnitude** is included"?

Comment: @Lee Mosher yes, typo

Comment: so it's the set of  gaussian integer that have coprime real and imaginary part ?

Comment: @mercio you are correct.

Comment: I have seen this set before.  When you stand at the origin, these are the Gaussian integers you can see.  So it is not out of the question that the set has been given a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Visible lattice points*  ${}{}{}{}{}$

http://acm2006.cct.lsu.edu/doc/friday/f.pdf
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html
http://poj.org/problem?id=3090

Comment: No Wikipedia entry?

Answer (score 0):

Such quadratic integers are called *primitive*, e.g. see the discussion of primitive ideals and primitive quadratic forms in [Section 2.5 of H. Cohen, *A Course in Computational ALgebraic Numbr Theory*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hXGr-9l1DXcC&pg=225)